# AngularJS $location won't change the path correctly

Tags: angularjs

For some reason `$location.path` won't direct to the `detail.html`. The table rows are clickable and when you click them all the info vanishes and it shows nothing but the alert. Here is my controller script partly:

```html
var app = angular.module('list-module', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'list.html',
      controller: 'ListController'
    })
    .when('/detail', {
      templaterUrl: 'detail.html',
      controller: 'DetailController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

});

app.controller("ListController", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams",
  function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    $scope.customers = [{
      id: 0,
      Title: 'noora',
      order0: 'coffee',
      url: 'http://static.iltalehti.fi/terveys/teekuppi1308MZ_tr.jpg'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      Title: 'tom',
      order0: 'tea',
      url: 'http://papunet.net/sites/papunet.net/files/kuvapankki/Kahvi.jpg-dup.jpg'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      Title: 'lauri',
      order0: 'coce',
      url: 'http://static.makuja.fi/files/articles/1238382.515x325.jpg'
    }];

    $scope.detailView = function() {
      alert("click works");
      $location.path("/detail").replace();
      $scope.$apply();

    };

  }
]);
```

Comment: Why do you use `.replace()` ? Shouldn't be `$location.path("/detail");`?

Comment: I have tried both and starting to be desperate. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "$scope.$apply();" and try.

Please refer here for detailed information as to when to use $scope.$apply()" http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html#apply"

Comment: I have tried with it and without. And with .replace() and without. Also i have tried to use linking <a href="/detail"> to the html but it does not work either. Tried with # also but no luck.

Comment: I suppose that the problem was that my angularjs/angularjs-router or some of the script i referred were out of date or wrong. The problem is gone now after I started over.